# Laravel jetstream change user with dropdown

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I have Laravel-8 Jetstream for authentication. I want to change logged-in user with a dropdown or any other way then log out and login. Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Comment: How are you using jetstream livewire or inertia?

Comment: I am using livewire